# DS-5 Support for Mac OS X

Tags: macos, arm, ds-5, streamline

I am trying to use DS-5 on Mac OS. DS-5 website, https://developer.arm.com/products/software-development-tools/ds-5-development-studio, says that DS-5 has support for Mac OS but I am unable to figure out what exactly is supported. I cannot find Mac OS installer for DS-5, for example. What support does DS-5 actually have for Mac OS X?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DS-5 has limited support for Mac OS X.

**DS-5 Full IDE** :
DS-5 does **NOT** have a full IDE installer for Mac OS X. If you need the full DS-5 IDE, then you will have to use a Windows/Linux machine/VM.

**DS-5 Eclipse Plugin** : You can install DS-5 community edition plugin into an existing Eclipse installation by following instructions in the http://ds.arm.com/ds-5-community-edition/getting-started-update-site/ page. This will give you the basic features of DS-5 listed under Community edition in the https://developer.arm.com/products/software-development-tools/ds-5-development-studio/editions page.

You can get full Streamline support, if you buy Professional or Ultimate edition license and update the license key in your Eclipse IDE.